# How can I effectively murder these rather grotesque disembodied rabbits?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

In the original *Legend of Zelda*, what's the most efficient way to kill a Pols Voice ghost?

[image: Seriously. That's a creepy bugger.]

On the original Famicom, it was possible using the built-in Mic, but that method appears to be unworkable nowadays.

Regular weapons (ie sword and boomerang) prove rather ineffective.

Comment: To clarify: Swords work.  (Boomerangs don't.)  Swords aren't the fastest/easiest method, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the NES lacks the Mic that the Famicom has, the Pols Voices were given a weakness to Arrows to compensate.

So basically, use arrows, that should kill them, and tadah, no more creepy rabbits.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is meant to be provided by an old man who gives a hint, quite near the room with Digdogger, the boss of Level 5.

Of course, you're likely to have suffered by these creatures quite a bit by then.  Also, the North American release's hint isn't really completely clear: "Secret Power is said to be in the arrow".  For a long time, I wondered if that was actually meant to also provide a hint on how to defeat Gannon (in an entirely different level).  I'm rather doubting that now, since [Legends of Localization: Zelda 1 Pols Voice section](http://legendsoflocalization.com/the-legend-of-zelda/gameplay/#polsvoice) points out that the Japanese version's text translates to something like "There are some creatures that are weak against sound."

Speaking of that website, it includes a reference to a few videos on YouTube that demonstrate some various ways that the creature is weak in various releases of this game.  Besides the [demonstration of sound killing Pols Voice on the Famicom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVXMf-60TK4) (a video that includes a yell), there is:

- In the Japanese version of the GBA re-release, pressing Select 4 times would do the trick.  Example: [YouTube video: Using select to kill the Pols Voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0-QHSLiP5U).
- [Using Microphone to kill Pols Voices in the Japanese 3DS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmXvra0Q7_s).